# Wordpress Content Based Navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I have a Wordpress Project which has the following Navigation Tree(similar):

```
Branch 1
- Infos about Branch (Is Branch 1 Custom Post Type)
- Infos About Services (Physical Therapie) (Overview)
- - Service1
- - Service2
- - Service3
- Infos About other Services
- - Service6
- Infos About other Services

Branch 2
- Infos about Branch2 (Is Branch2 Custom Post Type)
- Infos About Services (Physical Therapie) (Overview)
- - Service5 (Different Service)
- - Service2 (Exact Same Service)
- - Service3 (Same Service but branch specific Information)
- Infos About other Services
- - Service6
- Infos About other Services

General Information
Page2
Page3
Blog
```

So my goal is, when the user comes onto the landing page, he has some general Information, blog posts etc and shall chose a branch / nearest city.
When he continues to browse the page (with a chosen branch) the branch shall stick.

As for now I was using a get attribute with each request. but this seems kind of a shitty way to do is, as the rewrite rule does not match always.

Cookie Based Navigation seems to be odd for SEO.

the current website can be found here: https://www.physio-zentrum.ch

Any suggestions whats the best way to do this? Parenting is also not the solution, because the Services have different parents, according to the branch the user is visiting from.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh. okay. thanks. will post it there: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183507/wordpress-content-based-navigation

Comment: Don't mean to be offensive. There are some very smart WordPress guys on that site.  I think you would get better answers there.  Also, check previous submissions there for similar issues and answers.  One question.. can you use the wordpress taxonomy system to simplify your site's management?  Instead of having the 19 pages shown above, have just 11 with content based on taxonomy callouts?

Comment: Hmm I do that in kind of a way. So the Services are Custom Post types which are related to a Service type. I did this set up because it's easier for my customer to maintain his content. But thanks for the advice

Comment: You don't even need custom post types.  Remember posts can have multiple categories.  A single post could have "basel" and "wetzikon" (but NOT "st_gallen") and "praxis".  You would still be stuck with hidden values on the page or cookies to manage the (users location) navigation though, sigh.

Comment: yeah you are right. i managed that using Advanced Custom Fields and it's possibility to do custom n:m relations. But as you said, this wouldn't solve my problem ;)

Comment: Are you now using https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite  Will that work for you?

Comment: Yeas, played around with this. But it didn't fit my needs at the time. I will have another look at this. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74666/discussion-between-remo-l-and-zipzit).